# How to add an Share Action Extension to an Adobe Air iOS app.xml?

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, air

Since iOS 8 it's possible to register an app to be included in the iOS system wide *share menu* for various file types.

I'm creating an image editor iPhone app with Adobe Air for iOS 8.
What do I need to add to the app.xml to get listed in the share menu for `.jpg` files?

This is the iOS 8 share menu I'm speaking off:
[image]

EDIT: I came across this iOS8 Share Extension example code from [Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/Share/) - how to make the *receive content from safari* part work for Adobe Air based apps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.your-company.Share.ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>com.your-company.ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionPointName</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointVersion</key>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```